# Several unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, steam

I have recently tried downloading steam from the Ubuntu Software Centre but when I try to launch the program I got the bellow error message. Also my results when trying to install are this when it runs back Steam needs to install these additional packages:

```
    libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
[sudo] password for ellen: 
'.......................................................................................................
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4)
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
Press return to continue:
```

Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

it should install all the unmet dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error problems. Here's what worked for me (finally):

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-trusty:i386
```

(this will download about 57 files) Then...

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty:i386
```

(this will download about 23 files)

Now when you run Steam, it will download an update and you should be off and running. Good luck!